# How to replace broadcast receiver with android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE in Android 8?

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

I have developed an Android app that starts to display a notification and a view with some GPS data when the GPS is activated by any another app. The app launch is triggered using a broadcast receiver that has an intent filter with the android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE action. This works fine up to Android 8: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions. How can I achieve this in Android 8 and up?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: The only way is registering this `BroadcastReceiver` through the context so the app must be alive. Check this answer, it's the same problem but with other actions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671018/9771840